# What is the max length of a dart String?

Tags: string, dart

What is the maximum number of characters can dart `String` class can hold? I searched about this question in Google Search and I can't found the answer.

Comment: I doubt that there is any specified limit.  It likely is whatever the runtime is able to allocate.

Comment: Yeah, it's like "how much swap do you have?" :)

Comment: You mean that it depends on how much memory are left?

Comment: Likely, it depends on your machine's capabilities and on memory left, yes

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

When compiled for the web, the limit is the allowed JS `String` length.
Checking, it seems Chrome has a 0x1FFF_FFE8 limit on string length, Firefox uses 0x3FFF_FFFE.

On the Dart native VM, the limit is memory (and the size of integers, but so far the 64-bit integers cannot be a limiting factor on contemporary hardware. You can't actually have 2^64 bytes of memory on any current 64-bit architecture.)
I ran into "Exhausted heap space" errors after trying to double a string of length 0x4_0000_0000 (16 Gb). At that point the code was already fairly slow, which is not surprising since the computer "only" has 32 Gb of physical memory.

If using a 32-bit VM, the memory limit will definitely be lower.